# Free Transform in Photoshop in Mac OS X, cannot click and move the cursor and manually inputting values?

Tags: macos, mac, adobe-photoshop, text-cursor, transform

I am a PC user and recently moved to Mac to work with Photoshop. A problem bugs me a lot is when I press "Command + T" and use the free transform tool, and I want to manually input some values, say changing 400px height to 300px, I cannot move the cursor with mouse click but only with arrow keys after the first click, unlike in PC. Is this a common problem with Mac OS X with Photoshop CS5? Thanks.

[image: Photoshop free transform value box]

Comment: Works here on Ps CC, but does take about a second to respond [even on a 3.4GHz 12-core with 64GB RAM !]

Comment: I am using OS X Yosemite on a iMac with 2.93GHz Core i7 8 GB, Ps CS5 12.0.4. Not sure why this happened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known bug with PS running on Mac OS. Our beast Mac Pros at work have this problem as well.